# Rails: configatron

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configatron

In my app I'm using [configatron gem](https://github.com/markbates/configatron). The problem is I dont't understand clearly where I should store configatron settings. I put `configatron.application_url = 'http://google.com/'` in config/configatron/defaults.rb but this is not working. In the view `configatron.application_url` displays `#<Configatron::Store:0x000001035afe70>`

Comment: did you restart your server?

Comment: show you env with `configatron.to_h`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood what the problem is. On the on the [github page](https://github.com/markbates/configatron) of Configatron developers suggest to install version 3.0.0.rc1. I downgraded Configatron to version 2.9.1 and everything worked. Thanks to all participants!

Comment: Great! Looks like I'm a bit late with my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've missed installation step. Run the following code in shell (from rails app directory):

```
rails generate configatron:install
```

It will generate appropriate initializer (and this initializer should load your configatron file).

For more details on Rails and configatron, feel free to consult [Rails section on configatron GitHub page](https://github.com/markbates/configatron#rails).

Comment: Try to set and log `configatron.application_url` inside of your initializer (not `default.rb`). Let's see if it works that way.

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working? Server fails to load? Or you don't see value in the console?

Comment: still #<Configatron::Store:0x000001035afe70>

Comment: Try to output `configatron.to_h` there.

Comment: Better variant - use `rails c` and play with it there. You know how to use rails console?

Comment: it's strange, but in rails console configatron.application_url displays correct

Comment: Is it possible that you running your console and application in a different environments?

Comment: No, both in development

Comment: What kind of server (WEBrick, Unicorn or something else) you use?